# How to update SQL table when a row is deleted in another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know if it is possible to update a column (or in general 'do something') in an SQL table when an event occurs in another.

More specifically I'd like to know if it is possible to change a value in a particular column in a child table when a row is deleted in parent table. Sort of `ON DELETE CASCADE`but without deleting rows just updating them.

The DBMS I am using is MS SQL Server (Express edition).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a trigger on the table that you're trying to base the event off of, or you can limit access (read the deletion) from that table to happen only through a stored procedure.  The code for changing whatever it is you want to change on the other would be maintained in the trigger or stored procedure.

I typically prefer the stored procedure route, but this is just my personal preference.

[Stored Procedures](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Stored_procedure)

[Database Triggers](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Database_trigger)

Comment: SQL Server has an OUTPUT clause that can simplify stored procedure work by writing data from the deleted rows to another table at the time the delete statement is executed. Other RDBMSs may have similar features.

Comment: Thanks! Just one note: I am using .NET Entity Framework to insert, delete, etc... Will the EF handle by itself the triggering or do I have to consider something else? Thanks!

Comment: You'll define the trigger at the database level.  Basically, you'll set it up so that each time a delete occurs on table X it will execute the trigger and do something to table Y.  In your application, you'll delete the row the same way you always have.  Note that this trigger will execute anytime a record is deleted from the table by any user.  If you want to have more flexibility in when and how it's executed, then you'll want to look at creating a stored procedure that is called by your application.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which DBMS you're using, but this should be possible using a trigger.

Assuming you're running MS SQL (which I'm guessing only because you don't specify a DBMS), check this out: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/Using-Triggers-In-MS-SQL-Server/

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if it is possible to
>   change a value in a particular column
>   in a child table when a row is deleted
>   in parent table. Sort of ON DELETE
>   CASCADE but without deleting rows just
>   updating them.

Yes e.g. the referential actions `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` and `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a trigger to do this.

Exact syntax depends on the `RDBMS` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's called a [trigger.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger)  We can give more specific info if you specify what RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use [database triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger)